# When to set Resource for ImageView in Android NavigationDrawer

Tags: android, null, imageview, navigation-drawer, oncreate

I have trouble deciding where to set the image of an ImageView contained in the Android NavigationDrawer.

My Android app has a NavigationDrawer that contains an ImageView nested into a couple of other elements inside the NavigationDrawer header layout (`app:headerLayout="@layout/navdrawer_header`), and my `navdrawer_header.xml` has the following structure:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/navdrawer_header">
    ...
    <ImageView android:id=@+id/image_view
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    ...
</LinearLayout>
```

I am setting the image (`img.jpg` in my drawable folder) via

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.img);
```

If called from `OnCreate` inside my `MainActivity`, the `imageView` will be null and the app crashes. The same if I move the above lines to `OnPostCreate` or even `OnStart`.
My understanding is that the view is not initialized yet at that point in time and therefore `findViewById` returns null. As a workaround, I have overwritten the `OnDrawerOpened` method and moved my code from above to that method.
This works just fine, but I am pretty sure it is not the best way to go since the method is called every time the drawer is opened. Instead, I would need a method that is only called once upon the creation of the drawer.

What is the best practice here, i.e. where should I set the resource of an ImageView that is contained in the NavigationDrawer?

I have tried omitting `view.` and experimented with different values of `view`, for example by assigning to it the `NavigationView` or `DrawerLayout` associated with my drawer, but it does not solve the issue.

Comment: Check this [link](http://androhub.com/navigation-view-material-design-support-library-tutorial/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
View view = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);

ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.img);
```